# Monitoring inbound and outbound internet traffic

Tags: internet, software-recommendation, monitoring, traffic

Is there software I can install to enable me to monitor inbound and outbound internet traffic for security reasons?

*I recently installed ubuntu and loving it because of speed and interface. I want to do what I can to make this the greatest OS I've ever worked with.  Can you provide suggestions as to what I should install or do?*

Comment: Hi @gijoemike and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We find on here that it works best if you keep can keep it to one specific question per question. For this reason I've edited your question to only ask about the traffic monitoring issue. We'd love it if you opened a new question to ask about the changes to your files.

Answer (score 8):

I personally use vnstat which works quite nicely as it just sits in the background. You can query it for hourly, daily, monthy stats and there's a nice web based frontend to it called jvnstat.

Here's some examples from my website:-

```
alan@bishop:~$ vnstat -m

eth0  /  monthly

   month        rx      |     tx      |    total    |   avg. rate
------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
  Dec '09     10.05 GiB |   38.33 GiB |   48.38 GiB |  151.54 kbit/s
  Jan '10     10.83 GiB |   50.71 GiB |   61.55 GiB |  192.76 kbit/s
  Feb '10      8.18 GiB |   63.24 GiB |   71.42 GiB |  247.65 kbit/s
  Mar '10     10.43 GiB |   93.92 GiB |  104.35 GiB |  326.83 kbit/s
  Apr '10     12.56 GiB |   85.59 GiB |   98.15 GiB |  317.63 kbit/s
  May '10     12.70 GiB |   94.37 GiB |  107.07 GiB |  335.35 kbit/s
  Jun '10     17.02 GiB |   95.04 GiB |  112.06 GiB |  362.66 kbit/s
  Jul '10     33.18 GiB |  177.08 GiB |  210.26 GiB |  658.52 kbit/s
  Aug '10     25.52 GiB |   37.25 GiB |   62.77 GiB |  196.60 kbit/s
  Sep '10     20.70 GiB |   55.09 GiB |   75.79 GiB |  245.29 kbit/s
  Oct '10     16.96 GiB |   60.15 GiB |   77.12 GiB |  241.52 kbit/s
  Nov '10     23.97 GiB |   72.45 GiB |   96.41 GiB |  502.29 kbit/s
------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
estimated     38.58 GiB |  116.62 GiB |  155.20 GiB |

alan@bishop:~$ vnstat -h
eth0                                                                     15:16
 ^                                                                  t
 |                                                                  t
 |                                                                  t
 |                                                            t    rt
 |      t                                                    rt    rt
 |      t              t                                     rt    rt
 |      t              t                                   t rt rt rt  t
 |      t     t  t  t  t     t     t     t                 t rt rt rt  t
 |     rt     t  t  t  t     t     t     t              t rt rt rt rt rt
 |  rt rt rt rt rt rt rt r  rt rt rt r  rt r  r  r  r  rt rt rt rt rt rt
-+--------------------------------------------------------------------------->
 |  16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15

 h  rx (KiB)   tx (KiB)      h  rx (KiB)   tx (KiB)      h  rx (KiB)   tx (KiB)
16      37374      32892    00      28233      90548    08      29588      18472
17      55325     148496    01      27162      32413    09      44442      48771
18      37293      23266    02      23543      75628    10      60487     111111
19      28184      79542    03      26526       9882    11     143143     177348
20      27952      75414    04      28217      76025    12     108370     100327
21      28963      78342    05      26732       9255    13     173459     227965
22      29337     118592    06      26586      13474    14      48390     110247
23      27454      15529    07      26874      11389    15      10813       8882
```

vnstat is in the repositories and takes just a moment to setup. There's a nice guide on the debian administration website:-

http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/330

Comment: Cute little ASCII graphic :)

Answer (score 3):

Network analyser tools:

- I suggest you install [wireshark](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/wireshark) and read its [documentation](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to install [iptraf](http://apt.ubuntu.com/i/iptraf) commandline tool.

Answer (score 1):

That is a question requiring a very nontrivial answer. The following tools could all be useful to deflect an attack:

```
nmap -A
netstat -lnptu
kill
the /proc filesystem 
iptables
the sentry tools suite
```

These tools give you a lot of control if you know how to use them and will require some good "hobby time" to learn.

Answer (score 1):

If your only interessted in how much traffic there is (not its destination) you could use a commandline tool called bmon.

Comment: I think `bmon` only shows real-time statistics

Answer (score 1):

**Cacti**

Cacti is a complete network graphing solution designed to harness the power of RRDTool's data storage and graphing functionality. Cacti provides a fast poller, advanced graph templating, multiple data acquisition methods, and user management features out of the box. All of this is wrapped in an intuitive, easy to use interface that makes sense for LAN-sized installations up to complex networks with hundreds of devices.

[image]

Installation:

```
sudo apt-get install cacti
```

[Click this to read about Cacti features](http://cacti.net/features.php)

Answer (score 1):

**Bandwidthd**

BandwidthD tracks usage of TCP/IP network subnets and builds html files with graphs to display utilization. Charts are built by individual IPs, and by default display utilization over 2 day, 8 day, 40 day, and 400 day periods. Furthermore, each ip address's utilization can be logged out at intervals of 3.3 minutes, 10 minutes, 1 hour or 12 hours in cdf format, or to a backend database server. HTTP, TCP, UDP, ICMP, VPN, and P2P traffic are color coded.

[image]

Download from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bandwidthd/).

Read more about [here](http://bandwidthd.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

**speedometer**

If you need a live monitoring of the inbound and outbound traffic rate across a network interface you can try [speedometer](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/speedometer/). I found this command-line based tool very user-friendly.

Install speedometer:

```
sudo apt-get install speedometer
```

Use the `-rx` and `-tx` options to display bytes received and transmitted on network interface. For example, if your network interface card name is `eth0` use the following command:

```
speedometer -rx eth0 -tx eth0
```

A live graph like the one shown blow will be displayed in the terminal window. By default, the graph is updated every second. You can change update intervals if you wish.

[image]

For more information read the man pages using [`man speedometer`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/speedometer.1.html) after installing.

Answer (score 0):

As far as your first question is concerned you can use **wireshark** network analyser to monitor traffic on your network interfaces. some tutorials are here

http://www.wireshark.org/docs/