# Can some one suggest a software to monitor and maintain record of total internet bandwidth usage

Tags: monitoring, bandwidth

Can some one suggest a software for a small home network to monitor the amount uploaded / download from the internet but not the local traffic on the LAN. I know there are similar questions like these

[How can you monitor internet data usage?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1459/how-can-you-monitor-internet-download-usage)

[Monitoring inbound and outbound internet traffic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13029/monitoring-inbound-and-outbound-internet-traffic)

but the suggested softwares in these questions like vnstat dont consider if the traffic is for local network or internet which means that I can not know if I am reaching my ISPs monthly cap on bandwidth. I have googled for this and found only one software i.e ipac-ng but it is not straight forward. I need something that I a normal user can use easily i.e without changing iptables rules or adding routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Do You Have Limited Internet Plan? Use NTM (Network Traffic Monitor)!" - http://www.webupd8.org/2010/12/do-you-have-limited-internet-plan-use.html

Comment: Hi your link may provide the correct answer for this question , but it would be a nice work if you include part of main answer also .

Answer (score 0):

I would check out conky (just go into the Ubuntu Software Center and type it in).

Then find some guides on how to use it, but it provides a wealth of options to monitor virtually every aspect of your computers performance. I do not use it regularly myself, but the options are extensive.

The firewall program 'firestarter' (again, in the software center) also monitors upload/download usage but only from when you turn it on each session.

Hope they point you in the right direction!