# What do the numbers on the speedometer 2.8 screen mean?

Tags: command-line, networking, monitoring, traffic

I'm running [speedometer 2.8](http://excess.org/speedometer/) which has been [recommended](https://askubuntu.com/a/915500/82144) in [various](https://askubuntu.com/a/638139/82144) answers [on this site](https://askubuntu.com/a/820216/82144) to monitor network utilization.  I have read the manual page and have searched on Google but I am not seeing it documented what the numbers on each interface mean.

For instance, when I am receiving data, I might see something like this:

```
RX: wlp3s0  2.73 MiB/s 2.52 MiB/s  947 KiB/s
```

A screenshot from the documentation shows:

[image: Screenshot from home page]

In addition, above these numbers to the right of the cyan ASCII graph are two vertical bars, one blue and one white which seem to be tracking two of these numbers, although I'm not sure which. This picture shows them circled in yellow.

[image: Screenshot example showing vertical bars at right]

I assume that maybe these three numbers represent the transfer rate during the last period as well as maybe average, minimum, or maximum values.  But it is unclear as to which might be which.

What specifically does each number refer to, and to which of these numbers do the blue and white graphs correspond?

Comment: I might be mistaken here, but watching those graphs on my system here it appears that the numbers are the averages over 2 seconds, 10 seconds and 40 seconds.  The far right column will stay more steady then the one to the left of it.  It may be averaging on those two far right columns as maybe 10 seconds and 40 seconds only, but I am not 100% sure.  `iftop` does something very similar.